# Drawing multiple Socket Instances to canvas and update on Move (Multiplayer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, socket.io

**The Plan**

I decided to Start experimenting with Node.js and Socket.io and look to make a game (or just a lobby that will draw and show each player as a block). Every time a client joins, then the server should take the class and instantiate a new object with player details that are given by the server(Random).

The server will then use socket.io and emit the new object to the client that connected so they can have the object and then be able to do things with it(In this case move).

The first thing the client should do is draw all the the users to the canvas and then draw the current client to the canvas too.

---

**The Problem**

I have gotten to the point where things are working and the server makes a new player object then sends it to the client and then the client will be able to draw itself to the canvas with the properties but i cant seem to have the client be sent to be drawn on the canvas of other users until I move the player.

When i open multiple browser Tabs then it works as expected with drawing the client as shown here:

### [image]

But when i move one of them then the one client does get drawn to the others successfully but the other clients all lose the object that was given to them for that moment until they move then it moves successfully everywhere else but then the other clients all lose the screen state where you get to see where they are all positioned. In short they are all on the screen and move accordingly to the correct places in all browers but you never see all the players when it happens it only shows one player at a time and that is the one moving (after you have first joined where you also only see yourself until someone moves but then you done see all the players only the last moved until someone or you moves). *View image below*

[image]

The above shows me focusing the middle tab and moving and the logs shows what happens (Note the other players all disappear and only the moving one gets shown)

---

**The Code**

I only have 2 files that I'm using and they are populated as follows.

*Server - nodejs*

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

http.listen(8000);

//server connections and routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'), function(request, response){
    if(request.url !== '/public') {
        response.sendFile( __dirname +'/error/index.html');
        console.log('Error 404 request, User tried accessing: ' + __dirname + request.url);
    }
});

var players = [];

//Lets create a function which will help us to create multiple players
function newPlayer() {
    this.name;
    this.id = 1;
    this.x = Math.random() * 500;
    this.y =  Math.random() * 500;
    //Random colors
    var r = Math.random()*255>>0;
    var g = Math.random()*255>>0;
    var b = Math.random()*255>>0;
    this.color = "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", 0.5)";

    //Random size
    this.radius = Math.random()*20+20;
    this.speed =  5;

    return {'name' : this.name,"x" : this.x,"y" : this.y,"color" : this.color, "radius" : this.radius,"speed" : this.speed}
}

//calls to the server and tracking connection of each new user
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var currentPlayer = new newPlayer(); //new player made
    players.push(currentPlayer); //push player object into array

    //create the player
    socket.broadcast.emit('createUsers', players);
    socket.emit('currentUser', currentPlayer);

    //user moved
    socket.on('moved', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('moving', data);
    });

    //disconnected
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        var i = players.indexOf(currentPlayer);
        players.splice(i, 1);
        socket.broadcast.emit('user left','User: ' + currentPlayer.name + ' Left');
        console.log(players);
    });

});

console.log('NodeJS Server started on port 8000...');
```

*Client Side - HTML*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Game Dev JS - 1</title>
    <link href="./ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
        Your Browser Does Not Support Canvas and HTML5
    </canvas>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/engine.js"></script>

</html>
```

*Client Side - CSS*

```
body{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#canvas {
    margin: 15px;
    background: #000;
}
```

*Client Side - Javascript*

```
var socket = io.connect(); //add socket object

//initializing the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    W = window.innerWidth,
    H = window.innerHeight;

var keys = {};

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true; 
}, false);

//check if ke is not being pressed or has lifted up
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);

socket.on('currentUser', function(newUser){
    ctx.fillStyle = newUser.color;
    ctx.fillRect(newUser.x, newUser.y, 25, 25);

    function update(){
        //moving player
        if(keys[38]){
            newUser.y -= newUser.speed;
            socket.emit('moved', newUser);
            console.clear();
            console.log('You Moving');
            console.log(newUser);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
            ctx.fillStyle = newUser.color;
            ctx.fillRect(newUser.x, newUser.y, 25, 25);
        } 
        if(keys[40]){
            newUser.y += newUser.speed;
            socket.emit('moved', newUser);
            console.clear();
            console.log('You Moving');
            console.log(newUser);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
            ctx.fillStyle = newUser.color;
            ctx.fillRect(newUser.x, newUser.y, 25, 25);
        } 
        if(keys[37]){
            newUser.x -= newUser.speed;
            socket.emit('moved', newUser);
            console.clear();
            console.log('You Moving');
            console.log(newUser);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
            ctx.fillStyle = newUser.color;
            ctx.fillRect(newUser.x, newUser.y, 25, 25);
        } 
        if(keys[39]){
            newUser.x += newUser.speed;
            socket.emit('moved', newUser);
            console.clear();
            console.log('You Moving');
            console.log(newUser);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
            ctx.fillStyle = newUser.color;
            ctx.fillRect(newUser.x, newUser.y, 25, 25);
        }
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
    update();
});

//moving player and updating on other clients
socket.on('moving', function(moveTo){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    ctx.fillStyle = moveTo.color;
    ctx.fillRect(moveTo.x, moveTo.y, 25, 25);
    console.clear();
    console.log('A Player Moved');
    console.log(moveTo);
});
```

---

**Notes**

I would host it somewhere on a fiddle for you to play around with but I dont know of any that will allow me to test with the node.js server and allow you to have a look at the code at the same time like JS fiddle. I'm still new to the Node and Socket.io and this is my first attempt s any help will be bonus for me. I'll Work on refactoring the code once the main functionality is in order.

*If you have npm installed and you install socket.io then you should be able to copy and paste this and it should work. My folder structer is below - This doesn't have any issues as everything loads correctly*

[image]

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as I never got a response to help validate my question. I managed to read through the book (or part there of of @JCD above) and managed to look at other applications and how they manage their applications using node.

I know it's not good practice to do any calculations on the node server so as a result I re-looked at the code of my client and server and updated it.

---

**Verdict**

---

*Client Side:*

I decided to have the client only display the current client and its properties as well as the other clients connected to the server. Using a loop, the client will be looping through an array of `JSON` objects that is generated by the server (All the sockets connected to the server). The client will then use the canvas to draw the objects to the canvas. The array will also automatically update when a new client joins this makes the client automatically appear on the other clients in the correct location. I am using request animation frame to check if the client is pressing a key and then it sends and updates the client properties while the server just broadcasts accordingly (the updated array that the clients will loop to draw to canvas).

*Server Side:*

The server will be responsivble for waiting for a client to send a key code to the server and if the condition is met, it will update the object that was assigned to that client with the new properties (Move when the correct key comes through - Gets sent to the server through the `RequestAnimationFrame()`).

---

**Code:**

*Client Side (HTML - Nothing Changed):*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Game Dev JS - 1</title>
    <link href="./ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500">
        Your Browser Does Not Support Canvas and HTML5
    </canvas>
</body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/engine.js"></script>
</html>
```

*Client Side (JS - Update):*

```
var socket = io.connect(); //add socket object

//initializing the canvas
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    W = window.innerWidth,
    H = window.innerHeight;

var keys = {};

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true; 
}, false);

//check if key is not being pressed or has lifted up
window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);

//game loop to make the game smoother
function gameLoop() {
    if(keys[38]) {
        socket.emit('pressed', 38);
        console.log('You are UP');
    }
    if(keys[40]) {
        socket.emit('pressed', 40);
        console.log('You are DOWN');
    }
    if(keys[37]) {
        socket.emit('pressed', 37);
        console.log('You are LEFT');
    }
    if(keys[39]) {
        socket.emit('pressed', 39);
        console.log('You are RIGHT');
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);

//the connected user joins and gets all the players on server
socket.on('welcome', function(currentUser, currentUsers){
    console.log(currentUser);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    //Lets reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

    //Lets blend the particle with the BG
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

    //players in lobby
    for(var i = 0; i < currentUsers.length; i++){

        ctx.beginPath();

        //Time for some colors
        var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, 0, currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, currentUsers[i].radius);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "white");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.4, currentUsers[i].color);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");

        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.arc(currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, currentUsers[i].radius, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }

    //player
    ctx.beginPath();
    //Time for some colors
    var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(currentUser.x, currentUser.y, 0, currentUser.x, currentUser.y, currentUser.radius);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "white");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.4, currentUser.color);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");

    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.arc(currentUser.x, currentUser.y, currentUser.radius, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fill();
});

//other users get updated with new players when teh new player joins
socket.on('currentUsers', function(currentUsers){
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    //Lets reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";

    //Lets blend the particle with the BG
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

    for(var i = 0; i < currentUsers.length; i++){

        ctx.beginPath();

        //Time for some colors
        var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, 0, currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, currentUsers[i].radius);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "white");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.4, currentUsers[i].color);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");

        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.arc(currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, currentUsers[i].radius, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    console.log('A new User has joined');
});

//if a player leaves, everyone gets new set of players
socket.on('playerLeft', function(currentUsers){
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    //Lets reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";

    //Lets blend the particle with the BG
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

    for(var i = 0; i < currentUsers.length; i++){

        ctx.beginPath();

        //Time for some colors
        var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, 0, currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, currentUsers[i].radius);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, "white");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "white");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.4, currentUsers[i].color);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");

        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.arc(currentUsers[i].x, currentUsers[i].y, currentUsers[i].radius, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    console.log('A Player Has left');
});


socket.on('PlayersMoving', function(players){
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    //Lets reduce the opacity of the BG paint to give the final touch
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

    //Lets blend the particle with the BG
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

    var players = players;
    var i = 0;
    function allPlayers(){
        for(i; i < players.length; i ++) {

        ctx.beginPath();

        //Time for some colors
        var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(players[i].x, players[i].y, 0, players[i].x, players[i].y, players[i].radius);
        gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "white");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.5, players[i].color);
        gradient.addColorStop(1, "black");

        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.arc(players[i].x, players[i].y, players[i].radius, Math.PI*2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        }
    }
    allPlayers();

});
```

*Server Side (NodeJS - Update):*

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

http.listen(3000);

//server connections and routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'), function(request, response){
    if(request.url !== '/public') {
        response.sendFile( __dirname +'/error/index.html');
        console.log('Error 404 request, User tried accessing: ' + __dirname + request.url);
    }
});

var players = [];

//Lets create a function which will help us to create multiple players
function newPlayer() {
    this.name;
    this.id = 1;
    this.x = Math.random() * 500;
    this.y =  Math.random() * 500;
    //Random colors
    var r = Math.random()*255>>0;
    var g = Math.random()*255>>0;
    var b = Math.random()*255>>0;
    this.color = "rgba(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ", 0.5)";

    //Random size
    this.radius = Math.random()*20+20;
    this.speed =  5;

    return {'name' : this.name,"x" : this.x,"y" : this.y,"color" : this.color, "radius" : this.radius,"speed" : this.speed}
}


//calls to the server and tracking connection of each new user
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var currentPlayer = new newPlayer(); //new player made
    players.push(currentPlayer); //push player object into array

    //create the players Array
    socket.broadcast.emit('currentUsers', players);
    socket.emit('welcome', currentPlayer, players);

        //disconnected
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        players.splice(players.indexOf(currentPlayer), 1);
        console.log(players);
        socket.broadcast.emit('playerLeft', players);
    });

    socket.on('pressed', function(key){
        if(key === 38){
            currentPlayer.y -= currentPlayer.speed;
            socket.emit('PlayersMoving', players);
            socket.broadcast.emit('PlayersMoving', players);
        } 
        if(key === 40){
            currentPlayer.y += currentPlayer.speed;
            socket.emit('PlayersMoving', players);
            socket.broadcast.emit('PlayersMoving', players);
        } 
        if(key === 37){
            currentPlayer.x -= currentPlayer.speed;
            socket.emit('PlayersMoving', players);
            socket.broadcast.emit('PlayersMoving', players);
        } 
        if(key === 39){
            currentPlayer.x += currentPlayer.speed;
            socket.emit('PlayersMoving', players);
            socket.broadcast.emit('PlayersMoving', players);
        }
    });
});

console.log('NodeJS Server started on port 3000...');
```

---

**Example**

[image]

---

I know its not the cleanest of ways to do things but this was a prototype and I hope it can help someone in the near future for a stepping stone that manages to run into the same issue and not have to go through the same trouble.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your client-side listener for the `moving` event will only ever allow a client to draw one player's position at a time. You're clearing the entire screen, erasing all the other positions, but then only redrawing the player who moved.

I would recommend reading Robert Nystrom's excellent Game Programming Patterns e-book http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html . It doesn't cover this specific case but you can extrapolate a lot from the sections on Observer, Game Loop, and Update. In your case you probably want the server to run the authoritative game loop and state, using observers to update state between client/server, and the clients displaying said state to the user with their own independent game loops.

Comment: I had a look at the book, still need to read through it but a good book and i will take this into consideration but I have found a solution that I will use for now where the loop will only be checking the events of the client and then sending it to the server. The server will then do the updating of the clients new properties and then emitting changes to the client and the other clients connected. then its all about looping on the client side and showing the current client and the others currently on the server too - I'll post a answer with the new code below soon but thanks!